# ¿como tomar datos de una tabla mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito tomar datos de una tabla que tienen un campo igual pero necesito que al imprimir esos datos no me salga uno....mas o menos algo asi

```
 mysqli_query($conect,"SELECT * FROM asd WHERE id_p=3")
 //tnego 4 datos con id_p = 3 pro quiero que el que esta seleccionado no salga 
 //tomamos los 3 peor si apso el id del que no quiero que salga ese no salga
```

Comment: no entendí si tenés un campo igual como vas a pretender que al seleccionarlo o intoducirlo no te salgan todos los campos que responden a esa descripción?

Comment: Basado en que concepto no tiene que salir alguno? pq si todos tienen el mismo id, cual es el que no tiene que salir?

Answer (score 2):

Utiliza mejor el driver de PDO.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM contacto';
$res = $database->execute($sql);
```

Donde database es un objeto PDO que se declara asi

```
$database = new PDO(
            'mysql:host=' . $clase::SERVER . ';dbname=' . 
            Constant::DATABASE,
            Constant::USER,
            Constant::PASS,
            array(
                PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'set names utf8'
            )
        );
```

La ejecucion devuelve true o false. Si es true hacemos lo siguiente:

```
   if($res){
        $sentencia = $database->getStatement();
        while($fila = $sentencia->fetch()){
            $contacto = new Contacto();
            $contacto->set($fila);
            $contactos[] = $contacto;
        }
   }
```

Luego devuelves el array donde lo guardas, lo recorres y vas sacando valores como un array normal.